# How to mock a protected/private method in a tested method?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have a Python Clas with 2 methods.

The first, `_getTemperature_()` is protected and the second one is a public method. I have to write a unitTest but I have no clue, how to mock the protected method? I just found tutorials to mock a public method which is used at the test direct. But not in a method which sould be tested.

```
class StateOn(self):

    #Temperature in °C
    _target = 15

    # currrent Temperature by Sensor in °C
    def _getTemperature_(self):
        return valueFromSensorXY()


    def validateTemperature(self):
        if self._getTemperature_() >= self._target:
            return StateOff()
```

Does someone can give me a hint, or an explaination to find a solution about this issue?

Comment: `def _getTemperature_()(self)` is not a valid syntax. There's no such thing called public and private, `_` is just a convention in Python and it doesn't change anything(it is special only in module imports).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
fake_temp = 15
with mock.patch.object(StateOn, '_getTemperature', return_value=fake_temp) as mock_temp:
    result = StateOn().validateTemperature()
    self.assertIsInstance(result, StateOff)
```

Comment: thank you for your very fast reply with perfect input. I substitue the @ to `with` and added into an method. Thank you!! :)

Comment: This solution does not actually seem to work for private methods. I get CLASS does not have the attribute __FUNCTION

Comment: @Corne private functions (functions starting with __function()) are obsfucated when a class is interpreted so they remain private. 
IE a function with the name __ex_function() may be assigned the name afsdlfkjasdfjasldjfasjdfasjdf() to make it private upon interpretation.

Answer (score 10):

A bit late to the party, but here's an alternative method:

```py
from unittest import mock

class MyClass():
    def __my_method(self):
        # Implement logic here...
        pass

def test_my_class():
    my_class = MyClass()
    my_class._MyClass__my_method = mock.Mock()
    # Run testing stuff...
```

By setting `my_class._MyClass__my_method` to `mock.Mock()` we effectively have a mock in place of the private method.

Note that we need to set `my_class._MyClass__my_method` and not `my_class.__my_method`, due to Python's [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) of private attributes.

Comment: God bless you, Sir. I have been at this problem for the last 3 days now :)

Comment: Is there a way, to assert call something of the method?

Comment: @OlivérPalotás yes, you can take a look to [unittest and Mock documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
def test_validate_temprature(self):
   state = StateOn()
   fake_temp = 15
   with mock.patch.object(state, '_StateOn__getTemperature_', return_value=fake_temp) as temp_mock:
       result = state.validateTemperature()
       self.assertIsInstance(result, StateOff)
       temp_mock.assert_called_once()
```